# SSIS Redirect to Error if Invalid Column

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package that uses a foreach loop to go through a folder full of excel files, do a bunch of stuff, and then insert some things into my database.

All of this works fine and dandy until it comes across a file that has a column spelt incorrectly (occasionally "metres" is spelt "meters"). This causes it blow up, and seeing as it doesn't recognise the column, I don't seem to be able to get it to redirect, log and continue with the rest of them.

Is this at all possible?

Otherwise I suppose I could skip the header row entirely and name them manually?

Thanks for any help you can offer! I'm totally new to SSIS :(

Comment: could you put a screen shot of your package for clear understanding ?

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi Hi, I'm not sure a screen shot of the package will help, basically it's just an Excel Source where the file being read changes, and sometimes the columns don't match the columns that the Excel Source expects.